# Report Viewer not showing report in MVC aspx view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, reporting

From the couple of days I am trying to create rdlc report in MVC 4. I just make a test Controller and ReportTest its action that return view. when I hit this url /test/ReportTest report page is opened but only header page is displayed as attached. when I try to observe this page behaviour in firebug it firebug shows a error message.
[image: error message in firebug]

```
[HttpGet]
    public ViewResult ReportTest()
    {
        return View("MyReports");
    }
```

this only happen when I am trying through controller. If I place report files out side the views folder and access this page its working fine as desired. Please help me out to resolve this issue.
I am working on MVC 4 with aspx view engine + SQL Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ReportViewer is a server side control, as used in WebForms. When you move it outside your Views folder, it uses the WebForms pipeline.

You'll either have to access it as a stand alone page like you are when moving it outside the Views folder or from an iframe in your MVC page.